# Why is this segfaulting? Can someone explain the valgrind error?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, struct, segmentation-fault, valgrind

So i have this program that compiles fine on my home machine, but as soon as i go to compile it on the university servers it breaks... :/ which is a massive pain in my ass. I have no idea where or what might be causing the error. Ill first start with the valgrind report from the university.

```
    ==13527== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13527== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13527== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13527== Command: ./main stock.dat coins.dat
==13527== 
==13527== Invalid write of size 8
==13527==    at 0x402762: load_data (in /RMIThome/shr/5/s3234575/Assignments2/main)
==13527==    by 0x4028BE: main (in /RMIThome/shr/5/s3234575/Assignments2/main)
==13527==  Address 0x6172676f72502074 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==13527== 
==13527== 
==13527== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==13527==  General Protection Fault
==13527==    at 0x402762: load_data (in /RMIThome/shr/5/s3234575/Assignments2/main)
==13527==    by 0x4028BE: main (in /RMIThome/shr/5/s3234575/Assignments2/main)
==13527== 
==13527== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13527==     in use at exit: 4,096 bytes in 19 blocks
==13527==   total heap usage: 19 allocs, 0 frees, 4,096 bytes allocated
==13527== 
==13527== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13527==    definitely lost: 1,868 bytes in 8 blocks
==13527==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13527==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13527==    still reachable: 2,228 bytes in 11 blocks
==13527==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13527== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==13527== 
==13527== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13527== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

So the error is saying it occurs in main? but doesnt show until it reaches the load_data function, or is it the error occurs in load_data which is called in main?

The following code is main.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include "assert.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "vm_menu.h"
#include "vm_utility.h"
#include "vm_options.h"
#include "vm_type.h"


#define NUMARGS 3

struct menu_item * displayMenu(struct menu_item * menu, struct vm * vendMachine);
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    struct vm *vm;
    vm = malloc(sizeof(struct vm));
    struct vm *vend;
      vend = malloc(sizeof(struct vm));
    struct menu_item menu_items[NUM_MENU_ITEMS]; 
 /*check if there are at least 3 arguments being passed through the command line */

    if(argc!=3)
    {
        printf("Insuffcient arguments \n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    menu_init(menu_items);
    /* initialise the vm */
    vm_init(vm);

    load_data(vm, argv[1], argv[2]);
    vend->item_list.head = vm->item_list.head;
    BOOLEAN RUNNING = TRUE;

while(RUNNING){


        vm->item_list.head = vend->item_list.head;

    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stdin);
    displayMenu(menu_items, vm);
}
    read_rest_of_line();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

I think the error is in the     struct menu_item menu_items[NUM_MENU_ITEMS];  because i havent initialised it to anything. But i am unsure how i can allocate memory to an array of structs using malloc?

the load data file is;

```
#include "vm_utility.h"


/* print list */
    void print_list(struct vm_node  *root) {
        while (root) {
            printf("%s",root->data->id);
            root = root->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
/*creates a item and initialise the values */

struct stock_item* setupNode(char *line) {
    struct stock_item *root;
    root = malloc(sizeof(struct stock_item));
    char *ptr;
    char *ptrs;
    const char del[2] = "|";
    const char delm[2] = ".";
    char *prices;
    strcpy(root->id, strtok_r(line, del, &ptr)); // returns the ID and stores in in the root node.
    strcpy(root->name, strtok_r(NULL, del, &ptr)); // returns the description and stores it in the root node.
    strcpy(root->description, strtok_r(NULL, del, &ptr)); // returns the description and stores it in the root node.
    prices = strtok_r(NULL, del, &ptr); // returns a string of the price for vm_item.
    char *dols = strtok(prices, delm);
    char *cents = strtok(NULL, delm);
    long int dol = strtol(dols,&ptrs,10);
    long int cent = strtol(cents, NULL, 10);
    root->price.dollars = dol;
    root->price.cents = cent;
    int quantity = strtol(strtok_r(NULL, del, &ptr), NULL, 10); // returns how many items are in stock.
    root->on_hand = quantity;
    return root;

}

/*creates the list within the vm->item_list*/
int addNodeBottom(char *val, struct vm_node *head){

    //create new node
    struct stock_item *data;
    data = malloc(sizeof(struct stock_item));
    data = setupNode(val);


    if (head->data == NULL)
        head->data = data;
    else
    {
        struct vm_node *current = NULL;
        for (current = head; current->next != NULL; current = current->next)
            ;

        current->next = malloc(sizeof(*current->next));
        current->next->data = data;
        current->next->next = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*creates coin array stores in vm->coins; */
struct coin * addCoins(char *val){
    char *ptr =NULL;
    char *ptrs =NULL;
    const char *deli = ",";
    char *denominations = strtok_r(val, deli, &ptrs);
    char *counts = strtok_r(NULL, deli, &ptrs);

    long int denomination = strtol(denominations, &ptr,10);
    long int count = strtol( counts,NULL, 10);

    struct coin *k;
    k = malloc(sizeof(struct coin));
    k->denom = denomination;
    k->count = count;
    return k;
}

/* 
 * Clears the input buffer.
 * */
void read_rest_of_line(void)
{
    int ch;
    while(ch = getc(stdin), ch!='\n' && ch != EOF)
        ;
    clearerr(stdin);

}

/* 
 * Initialises the vm data structure declared in main to safe initial
 * values.
 * */
BOOLEAN vm_init(struct vm * vm)
{
    struct vm_node * vmNode;
    vmNode = malloc(sizeof(struct vm_node));
    vmNode->next = NULL;
    vmNode->data = NULL;
    vm->item_list.head = NULL;
    vm->coinsfile = NULL;
    vm->foodfile = NULL;
    return FALSE;
}

/* 
 * Loads data from the .dat files into memory. 
 * */
BOOLEAN load_data(struct vm * vm, const char * item_fname, 
        const char * coins_fname){

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(item_fname, "r+");
    char buf[256];
    struct vm_node *vmNodes;
    vmNodes = malloc(sizeof(struct vm_node));
    vmNodes->data = NULL;
    vmNodes->next = NULL;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file) != NULL) {
        addNodeBottom(buf,vmNodes);
    }
    vm->item_list.head = vmNodes;

    fclose(file);
    /*now open coin file*/

    FILE *fileCoin;
    fileCoin = fopen(coins_fname, "r+");
    char bufCoin[256];
    int i = 0;
    //vmNode->next = NULL;
    struct coin *j;
    while (fgets(bufCoin, sizeof bufCoin, fileCoin) != NULL) {

        j = addCoins(bufCoin);
        vm->coins[i] = *j;
        free(j);
        i++;
    }
    /**/
    /* Test reason for reaching NULL. */
        fclose(fileCoin);

    return FALSE;
}

/* 
 * Frees all dynamically allocated data.
 * */
void system_free(struct vm * vm)
{
    /* The UNUSED() function is designed to prevent warnings while your
     * code is only partially complete. Delete this function call once
     * you are using vm in your own code */

}
```

Also to make life easier ill share the typedefs for all of the structs used.

```
    typedef enum truefalse
{
    FALSE, TRUE
} BOOLEAN;

/* Each price will have a dollars and a cents component */
struct price
{
    unsigned dollars,cents;
};

/* The different denominations of coins available */
enum denomination
{
    FIVE_CENTS, TEN_CENTS, TWENTY_CENTS, FIFTY_CENTS, ONE_DOLLAR, 
    TWO_DOLLARS, FIVE_DOLLARS, TEN_DOLLARS
};

/* Each coin in the coins array will have a denomination (20 cents, 
 * 50 cents, etc) and a count - how many of that coin do we have on hand
 */
struct coin
{
    enum denomination denom;
    unsigned count;
};

/* The data structure that holds the data for each item of stock
 */
struct stock_item
{
    char id[IDLEN+1];
    char name[NAMELEN+1];
    char description[DESCLEN+1];
    struct price price;
    unsigned on_hand;
};

/* The data structure that holds a pointer to the stock_item data and a
 * pointer to the next node in the list
 */
struct vm_node
{
    struct stock_item * data;
    struct vm_node * next;
};

/* The head of the list - has a pointer to the rest of the list and a 
 * stores the length of the list 
 */
struct vm_list
{
    struct vm_node * head;
    unsigned length;
};

/* This is the head of our overall data structure. We have a pointer to 
 * the vending machine list as well as an array of coins. 
 */
struct vm
{
    struct vm_list item_list;
    struct coin coins[NUMDENOMS];
    char * foodfile;
    char * coinsfile;
};
```

Valgrind at home:

```
    ==9814== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9814== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9814== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9814== Command: ./main stock.dat coins.dat
==9814== 
Main Menu:
    1. Display Items
    2. Purchase Items
    3. Save and Exit
Administrator-Only Menu:
    4. Add Item
    5. Remove Item
    6. Display Coins
    7. Reset Stock
    8. Reset Coins
    9. Abort Program
Select your option (1-9):
```

Comment: Try running valgrind on your program at home.

Comment: @JimBalter this is what i get when i run it at home

(==9814== Memcheck, a memory error detector

==9814== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.

==9814== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info

==9814== Command: ./main stock.dat coins.dat

==9814== 

Main Menu:

 1. Display Items

 2. Purchase Items

 3. Save and Exit

Administrator-Only Menu:

 4. Add Item

 5. Remove Item

 6. Display Coins

 7. Reset Stock

 8. Reset Coins

 9. Abort Program

Select your option (1-9):

Comment: Compile with debug info (and full warnings) and run your program in a debugger to pinpoint the issue. (Error is triggered in load_data, doesn't necessarily imply that the bug is there though.)

Comment: That doesn't seem like complete output from valgrind.

Comment: @JimBalter that was a complete output, as on the university server the code doesnt even compile to the print menu function...

Comment: @Mat i just  put it through the debugger and i still cannot find anything. So flipping frustrating

Comment: Well, post the backtrace and show where in your code the matching line number is.

Comment: @Mat this is what i get: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040260c in load_data (vm=0x6172676f72502074, item_fname=0x7fffffffe6b4 "stock.dat", coins_fname=0x7fffffffe6be "coins.dat")
    at vm_utility.c:132
132  vm->item_list.head = vmNodes;

Can i not set vm->item_list.head which is a struct of vm_node, to vmNodes, which is also of type vm_node?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is your home machine also 64-bit? It's possible that your code is not 64-bit clean, but the university's compiler is emitting 64-bit binary. If your home system is building a 32-bit binary, that could be the problem.

Comment: @CBHacking yeah my machine is 64bit. The problem lies with the following line. vm->item_list.head = vmNodes; but i am not sure how else to set one struct to another struct.

Comment: Also, why are you using Valgrind instead of a debugger like gdb or ddd? A debugger will break on the instruction that causes the signal and let you explore the state of the process (including what line it's on!) at that time. Way more useful when trying to nail down a segfault. Valgrind is mostly a tool to find memory leaks and such.

Comment: @JoshuaTheeuf: are you using the `-g` option when compiling so that debug symbols get created?  That should make `valgrind` provide better information about the location of the error.  Also it will enable you to effectively use `gdb` to debug, which might be your next step.

Comment: `while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file) != NULL) {
        addNodeBottom(buf,vmNodes);
    }` inserts the same node for every line read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Valgrind says that the illegal write is occurring at `Address 0x6172676f72502074`.

If you look at that address as ASCII characters, it's: `argorP t`, or converting from little endian: `t Progra`.

This looks like part of one of your menu items, "9. Abort Program". Maybe the bug is that `menu_init()` is writing past the end of the `menu_items[]` array?

I'd guess that stepping through your program in a debugger should find the problem quick enough.

Comment: @JoshuaTheeuf: addresses in programs usually have certain patterns because they come from one of 3 places: code, stack or heap. If you look at the addresses in the valgrind or debugger output (`0x402762`, `0x4028BE`, `0x7fffffffe6b4`, etc), you'd notice that `0x6172676f72502074` sticks out.  Once you notice that the address looks odd, it's not a big step to also notice that the byte values (0x61, 0x72, 0x67, 0x20 etc.) seem to fall in the range of ASCII characters.

Comment: Good eye ... I habitually look for that pattern but missed it in all that valgrind output.